# php/html help - Undefined Index

Tags: php

**I have to make a form on php/html asking simple questions such as gender, size, etc., and when i press submit, the next page says undefined index. It says that gender is not defined. Can someone help me and tell me what my mistake is?**

```
<?php 
        $gender = $_GET["gender"];
        echo "fksfjlsdflk $gender";
    ?>

     ("male" or "female")
            <input type="text" name="gender">
        <br />
        <br />
        Please type your preference of size
        <br />
        <br />
        "S" "M" "L" "XL"
            <input type="text" name="size">
        <br />
        <br />
        Please type your preference of colour   
        <br />
        <br />
        "Argent" or "Azure"
            <input type="text" name="colour">
        <br />
        <br />
            <form action="JacketConfirmation.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="Save My Preferences">
            </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value of gender from $_GET, make sure you define the gender value in query string (url) or initialize the valriable gender.

Answer (score 0):

make sure with form "method" attribute
after watching your code it seems that you are using GET Method so define method = get in form

ex 
    form action="process.php" method="get"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["gender"]))
{
    $gender = $_GET["gender"];
    echo "fksfjlsdflk $gender";
}
?>
<form action="JacketConfirmation.php" method="get">
    ("male" or "female")
    <input type="text" name="gender">
    <br />
    <br />
    Please type your preference of size
    <br />
    <br />
    "S" "M" "L" "XL"
    <input type="text" name="size">
    <br />
    <br />
    Please type your preference of colour   
    <br />
    <br />
    "Argent" or "Azure"
    <input type="text" name="colour">
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save My Preferences">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your form tag like

```
<form method="get">Insert your input field</form>
```

and write your php code like

```
$gender = $_GET["gender"];
```

or

```
$gender = $_REQUEST["gender"];
```